# Riley Riddle What Am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix is where I reside.
>
> My suffix is why I hide.
>
> My infix suggests greed.
>
> I'm also known for speed.

Hint 1:

> I step on nails,
>
>
>  I leave you trails.

Hint 2:

> What leaves **you** trails?

Comment: the word "snail"comes to my mind but i can't support it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are a

> stallion

My prefix is where I reside.

> a horse stall

My suffix is why I hide.

> lion --> a predator

My infix suggests greed.

> all --> coveting everything

I'm also known for speed.

> a racehorse

Hints:

> I step on nails: horseshoes are attached through nails.

> I leave **you** trails: as pointed out by Stiv, the horse hoofprints are U-shaped due to the shape of the horseshoe. My original remark: something to do with [trail riding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail_riding) or horse racing tracks?

Answer (score 5):

This is a stretch, but you might be:

> A seagull

My prefix is where I reside.

> At sea

My suffix is why I hide.

> To gull: to deceive

My infix suggests greed.

> Ag is the chemical symbol for silver (holding on to too much silver?).

I'm also known for speed.

> Not the fastest birdie out there, but check out [this article](https://dailytimes.com.pk/440223/worlds-fastest-seagull-stuns-experts-by-flying-520-miles-from-the-channel-islands-to-spain-in-just-seven-days/).