# Riley Riddle What Am I? #2

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is where you reside
>
> My suffix is why you hide.
>
> My infix suggests greed,
>
> I also make you read.

Hint:

> Where does *everyone* reside in?

---

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Riley Riddle What Am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/100187/70545)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to QuantumTwinkie, I think the answer is

> Homework

My prefix is where you reside

> Home

My suffix is why you hide.

> Possibly [ork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ork_(folklore)), a demon from which on should hide, or could also be **work**.

My infix suggests greed,

> Mew = stable usually with living quarters built around a court.
>  As Quantum Twinkie suggested, could also be **me**.

I also make you read.

> Reading is a big part of **homework**

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> [Homer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homer)

My prefix is where you reside

> Home

My suffix is why you hide.

> ER can mean Emergency Room, so you may try to hide from something(Covid-19) in order to prevent a visit to the ER.

My infix suggests greed,

> "Me" can suggest vanity

I also make you read.

> Homer is an ancient Greek author.